# Problem in login screen

Tags: package-management

After removing lubuntu-desktop there is still a option to run a lubuntu session in login option. How to fix it?Is there any package which is not removed yet?

Comment: Look in `/usr/share/xsessions` and delete any lubuntu-related entries.

Comment: These file were not being deleted. Can you help in this matter

Comment: `sudo rm /usr/share/xsessions/xxx.desktop` where you'll change `xxx` to `lubuntu` or whatever you want to remove.